# Web application testing on Mobile browser

Tags: mobile, web

Currently we are working on one of the web app for Mobile (that will cover iOS and Android devices).

So my question here is what should be the strategy for testing web apps:

1. Is it necessary to check on all possible popular devices and with all possible popular web browsers for devices?

Comment: Well, that depends on what devices your users will have, and how risk-averse you need to be. Do you have any more background about your situation?

Comment: Actual speaking there is no particular requirement. Its like that our client has one web site for travels that he want to support for Mobile Devices specially Android (phones and tablets) and iOS (iPhone and iPad).

Comment: For iOS there are few devices and u can test on them comfortabally but for android you can go for some standard sizes of screen and most popular devices instead of all popular devices

Comment: @Wasi: You mean to say no need to test on all popular devices just to go for standard resolutions and that will help. But will the configuration of device matter? like the RAM of the device on which the performance of the web site will depend? I am not confident about this and just want to confirm.

Comment: @Subzero: Obviously configuration matters but I don't think it would be an easy task to test on all popular browsers. You have two options 1) Ask the client what all devices he wants the site to be compatible. 2) do research on most selling Devices and choose a set which fulfills most of the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a web application which needed to be optimized for Mobile.

Our software uses the User Agent String all browsers send to determine if the requests are coming from a desktop device or a mobile device. If the latter, we respond with a mobile-enabled UI.

For our testing, we are able to perform a very high percentage of our functional testing using a desktop browser like Firefox or Chrome simply by faking the User Agent String. That way, the server thinks we are coming in via a mobile device, even when we aren't.

More details here: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2014/02/have-you-ever-faked-it-i-have.html

Answer (score 1):

I have been testing ion mobile for sometime.As per my view a mobile Web application is viewable by users around the world, even if you’re initially targeting only users in a single country or on a single network. Therefore you need to check your application on as many as possible devices, this will cover the risks of application failures and other issues and improve the market value of the app.

For iOS we can check it on all devices as they are few in numbers, but for android this becomes a problem as we have quite a large no. of devices for android.
In my opinion you must test it with the all standard sizes and resolutions, that would make the application secure to a good extent.Also check it with some standard configuration as specified by you for your application.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer to your question above as a [software testing company](https://www.qasource.com/software-testing-company), we think its better to use Browser Stack to perform your web application testing on Android and iOS. Moreover, you should also have a trace of the devices customers are using so that you can better have a hands on on which devices you need to test.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary to test your web app over popular Android and iOS devices.

Here’s why?

Web apps are like information-based websites. The change in size, complexity, shorter implementation cycles in Agile and frequent shifts in requirements pose various QA and testing teams' obstacles. However, testing a web app is not an easy task and relies on multiple aspects, such as browser compatibility, application performance, security mechanisms, etc.

Therefore it becomes necessary to test your web apps over different devices and viewports. Companies need to hire skilled testers to test all website facets across multiple platforms, browsers, and devices. Testers must incorporate the best strategies to implement web application testing to deliver appropriate test results in less build time.

Best strategies you can follow for Web Application testing:

- **Cross-Browser Compatibility Testing**

With more people visiting websites on their smartphones and tablets, businesses are finding more avenues to make their websites mobile-friendly. A responsive web design ensures that web apps offer a rich user experience on every platform. Therefore it becomes necessary to conduct cross-browser compatibility testing of websites to ensure it is compatible over other browser versions.

- **Load Testing**

Incredibly well-developed websites often suffer from severe failure as network traffic rises abruptly. Often minor shortcomings in coding or architecture can adversely affect the performance of the website. Therefore, it is necessary to perform load testing and determine how the application performs under various loads.

- **Usability Testing**

It is crucial to determine the usability of the application based on the most suitable parameters. Doing usability testing on the application before it is launched is a standard protocol. Usability testing includes many criteria such as speed, UI, accessibility & readability.

- **Security**

A single flaw will lead to a significant breach of data that can bring down even the biggest enterprises, with negative impacts, significant economic consequences, and a lack of public faith. It is vital to ensure that the web application is extensively checked on the safety level.

Now for mobile web testing on different mobile devices, various tools are available in the market such as [LT Browser](https://www.lambdatest.com/lt-browser) offered by LambdaTest. It is a developer-friendly tool that lets you perform responsive testing of your web apps and websites across 45+ pre-installed devices. Whether it is iOS, Android, or even a Macbook, you will get all resolution in the LT Browser.

If you want to test on multiple browsers, you can leverage [LambdaTest](https://www.lambdatest.com/feature) to test across various browsers on Android, and iOS platforms.